# Issues Displaying a ListView of All Installed Apps and Implementing an OnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I am trying to write a very simple app that displays the name of every installed app on the device in a listview. I am using Google's ListView tutorial as a base.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
                (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, ": Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.list_item, list)
            {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

                final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable);

                return convertView;
            }

            };
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                // On Item Click Activity
                // This is where I want to send the Package Name of the app selected to be passed to a method.


            }
          });
    }




 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE: I now need to use an OnItemClickListener to pass the Package Name of the App selected to a method.

Comment: Check your LogCat to find what exception is being raised. Post it here if that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Could you check the error in the logcat and display it here

Comment: It turns out that this only force closes in the emulator, works okay on an actual device. Unfortunately the package info displays like this: ResolveInfo{4053e448 com.alphonso.pulse.NewsRack p=0 o=0 m=0x108000} Any ideas on how to make this more human read-able?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To display your activities' names correctly in the list, you should override the `getView` method of your `ListAdapter`, and set some of your local variables as final (to work with inner class):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
            (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, ": Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
                applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    }

    final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.list_item, list)
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                ((TextView)convertView).setText(text);
                return convertView;
            }
        };
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

This way you have your custom `ArrayAdapter` implementation, which displays the proper label of applicationinfo in the `TextView`.

You can also achieve this, if you create a new `ArrayList<String>`, and populate it inside the for cycle where you log the applications:

```
final ArrayList<String> labelList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
{
    Log.i(TAG, ": Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
            applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
    labelList.add(rInfo.activityInfo.
            applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
}

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
        R.layout.list_item, labelList);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Then you use this new `labelList` as the source of your `adapter`.

**Update**
To include the icon into the item renderers, the overridden `getView` method would look like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
        applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
    ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

    final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
    ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable);

    return convertView;
}
```

and your `res/layout/list_item.xml` layout file has to contain the **`text`** `TextView` and the **`image`** `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply! I am getting ViewGroup and TextView cannot be resolved to a type errors in Eclipse.

Comment: either `Ctrl + Space` after them, or just add the necessary imports manually: `import android.view.ViewGroup;` and `import android.widget.TextView;` at the top of your class.

Comment: Thanks so much... I don't know why Eclipse didn't suggest importing them.... odd. I am probably asking too much here, but do you know of an easy way to include the app's icon in the listview?

Comment: For this you should have a new item renderer xml with an `ImageView` beside the `TextView` (packed into a `LinearLayout` for ex.). And to retrieve the icon, you can call `final Drawable d = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);`. Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you for your continued help!! Unfortunately, I am getting a Force Close now, logcat gives the ArrayAdapter error: "You must supply a resource ID for a TextView" Any ideas?

Comment: Yes: since you are using an `ArrayAdapter`, the resource id in its constructor should be a reference to a `TextView`. This `TextView` is inflated by default by the `ArrayAdapter`. You can however avoid this exception, if you don't call the `super.getView(position, convertView, parent);` from the `getView` method of the adapter. Please see the update, how it works.

Comment: I am having some issues with implementing an OnItemClickListener.. I want it to pass the package name of the app selected to a method... I will update my main post with the code. Your help is GREATLY appreciated!!!!

Comment: For this you should really ask a new question, not extending this one, to keep both the question and the answers focused on a specific issue, not on a specific person's composite goal. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996803/onitemclicklistener-that-passes-the-package-name-of-the-app-selected-to-a-method