# OnItemClickListener that passes the Package Name of the app selected to a method... Help

Tags: android

UPDATE: Now looking for Package Name as opposed to PID

I have an app that diplays a listview of all the installed apps on the device. I want to create an OnItemClickListener that passes the Package Name of the app selected to a method.

Here is my code:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    public static final int Menu1 = Menu.FIRST;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list =
                (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
        {
            Log.i("Installed Applications " + rInfo.activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString(), null);
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo> adapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<ResolveInfo>(this, R.layout.list_item, list)
            {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                if (convertView == null)
                    convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                        inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

                final String text = list.get(position).activityInfo.
                    applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);

                final Drawable drawable = list.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
                ((ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageDrawable(drawable);

                return convertView;
            }

            };
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

                // On Item Click Activity

                // This is where I would like to pass the package name to a method
            }
          });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the package name for the `activityInfo` member of the `ResolveInfo` instance whose item you just clicked on:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
        final String packageName = list.get(position).activityInfo.packageName;
        Log.i("PACKAGE", packageName);
        //TODO: Pass this packageName to a method
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have more than one PID in the application. Take a look at the ActivityManager documentation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Use this as a base:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> activities = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (int i=0; i< activities.size(); i++)
    Log.d ("PID INFO", "Activity " + i + " - PID: " + activities.get(i).pid);
}
```

And, BTW, don't post so much code next time. It is not relevant for your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting an error on the for statement that says: "The method length() is undefined for the type List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo>  Any ideas?

Comment: I have scrapped the PID idea and am now looking for the OnItemClickListener to pass the Package Name of the app selected in the ListView to a method.

Comment: @Frank my bad! It's size(), not length() for a List! That part is just to iterate through the results. You *might* need only `activities.get(0).pid`

Comment: @Frank try `String myPackageName = getComponentName().getPackageName ();` from your Activity

Answer (score 0):

It is fundamentally wrong to try to associate pids with apps.  One app can run in multiple pids, one pid can run multiple apps.  Whatever you are actually trying to do (you don't say so it is hard to give useful help), this is not the way.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will use package name instead... any ideas?