# Java - Android - Installed packages' icons not showing in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, icons

I'm trying to load installed packages' icons into a listview, but they are not showing in anyway, searched and used everything I found on the web but they just won't show, while they work if I use

```
 R.drawable.ic_launcher
```

So I guess it's not a layout-related issue.
Here's the code I'm using

```
for(int i = 0; i < numeroElementi; i++){

boolean nonSystem = (packages.get(i).flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0;

if(nonSystem == true){

    HashMap<String,Object> app = new HashMap<String,Object>();

    app.put("appName", packages.get(i).loadLabel(pm)); // these both work
    app.put("appPackageName", packages.get(i).packageName);

    try {
        //app.put("appIcon", pm.getApplicationIcon(packages.get(i).packageName));
        //app.put("appIcon", packages.get(i).icon + "");
        //app.put("appIcon", packages.get(i).loadIcon(pm));
        app.put("appIcon",packages.get(i).icon);
        //app.put("appIcon", R.drawable.ic_launcher); <- this works
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        app.put("appIcon", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    }

    installedList.add(app); 
}
}
```

Is then there another way to grab the icon? As said earlier, if I force the ic_launcher icon, then it works... testing with packages.get(i).icon I found out that some of the voices have got the ic_launcher icon shown, so I thought that method just directed to that specific icon... anyone can help me get this work, please?

Comment: Found a appropriate solution to the question [At THIS THREAD][1] and it worked for me.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995187/issues-displaying-a-listview-of-all-installed-apps-and-implementing-an-onitemcli